# Why does iAd banner interferes with my UIView animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, uiviewanimation

I have an iAd that I created following this [tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/) and for some reason when the iAd shows-up any animation going on at that time stops. In other words the animations work fine until the iAd apears and as soon as the iAd apears any animation going at that moment stops or it goes back to its original position without finishing the animation.

This is the code I have for the iAd

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
    _adBanner.delegate = self;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

And this is one of the animations I have

```
- (IBAction)showHideBlackboard:(id)sender
{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^
        {
            self.controlsView.frame= CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 250);           
        }completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
            {
                self.drawingView.alpha = 1.0;
                self.drawingView.frame= CGRectMake(10, 10, 350, 350);
            }completion:nil ];
        }];  
}
```

Any idea why does the iAd interferes with UIView animations?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps first try using the newer UIView animation paradigm for both. For instance, use the animateWithDuration method for the banner just like you do for your blackboard.

Comment: I will try that and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't make a difference, in fact I deleted all of the animations completely and still doesn't work.

Comment: Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I would need to see all of the source code to help further. Sorry!

Comment: fs_tigre what did you find about iAd interfering with animations? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any good solution, I ended up changing my app layout and behavior. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem. It turned out that avoiding the option

`self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

in my UIView subclass solved the problem.